# change UITextField BackGround Color by LongPress

Tags: ios, uitextfield

All Boxes is `UITextField`s. I want change background color when user long press on `UITextField`.
Which TextField had a long press that UITextField color is change, not all `UITextField`s.

[image: In My View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. Please note that one gesture recognizer can be attached to one view.
Here is code example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Array that holds your textfields
    NSArray *myTextFields;
    for (UITextField *textField in myTextFields) {
        //Creating UILongPressGestureRecognizer
        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
        //Attaching it to textfield
        [textField addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
    }
}
//Handling long press
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Comment: when long press on text field it show magnifier view And keyboard is Appear but not change background Color

Answer (score 3):

Try to use like this...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gs = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeBackground:)];
    [textFld addGestureRecognizer:gs];
}

- (void)changeBackground:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gs
{
     [self.view endEditing:YES]; // Edited 

     UITextField *txtFld = (UITextField *)gs.view;

     [txtFld setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: when long press on text field it show magnifier view And keyboard is Appear but not change background Color

Comment: its wrking at my end. Because i've implemented it. And see my edited answer little bit i've changed .

Comment: it is not go to the - (void)changeBackground:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gs
when i long press on text field

Comment: It goes dear . I think your doing somthing wrong.I'm pretty sure about it. This code is working proper at my end.